# How to recover the password for a MyOpenID ID in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, myopenid, account-recovery

First of all, thanks to the Meta Team that I'm again able to post questions. Now my problem is here:

I have two user IDs on http://www.stackoverflow.com associated with the *same Gmail* account and also have the MyOpenID account for both user IDs. One is

http://www.echo-die.myopenid.com/ and another which I always logged in via Gmail, but in my **[profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155861/diecho)** there is written

> openid (swap)  - MyOpenID (xkeshav)
>   alt openid (delete) - Google (xkeshav@gmail.com)

So I think I can log in via a **MyOpenID** account as well, but when I try to login with a password, I always get a message about wrong username or password, so I click on recover password, I get a mail on my Gmail, but in the mail there is a link to reset password for  **echo-die** account, not the **xkeshav**.

How do I retrieve the MyOpenID password for `xkeshav`?

Thanks all for helping me always. :)

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow can't provide you with a password recovery on `myopenid.com` since it does not belong to Stack Overflow.

To recover your password, you must visit the MyOpenID site and ask for password recovery from them, using the username or email you used for inscription.

Remember that with OpenID you authenticate with an existing account (for example, I authenticate with my Gmail account, that has nothing to do with Stack Exchange. They do not know account properties, like the password, etc... But they can retrieve my profile from it, and ask Google if I'm authenticated).